# How to initialize DateTime property to show Date.Now

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to set DateTime Field to display current time and date.

```
 public DateTime Date { get; set;  }
```

What I try so far to pass in setter `Date.Now` but doesn't work.
I am asking because I need to display DateTime.Now in View but this items should be hidden from `User`.
User can only see DateTime but can not `Edit`.
Also in Controller I use something like but doesn't work

```
 DateTime Date = DateTime.Now;
```

Any idea where I made mistake and how to fix this issues ?

**UPDATE**

Here is my Controller

```
 public NotesController(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

 public IActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<Notes> notes = _db.Notes.Include(u => u.Patient);
            return View(notes);
        }

        //Upsert GET
        public IActionResult Upsert(int? Id)
        {
            DateTime Date = DateTime.Now;
            
            NotesVM notesVM = new NotesVM()
            {
                Notes = new Notes(),

                PatientSelectList = _db.Patients.Select(i => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = i.FirstName + i.LastName,
                    Value = i.Id.ToString()
                })

            };

           

            Notes notes = new Notes();
            if (Id == null)
            {
                // this is for create
                return View(notesVM);

            }
            else
            {
                // this is for edit
                notesVM.Notes = _db.Notes.Find(Id);
                if (notesVM.Notes == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                return View(notesVM);
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Upsert(NotesVM notesVM)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                if (notesVM.Notes.Id == 0)
                {
                    //Creating
                    _db.Notes.Add(notesVM.Notes);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Updating
                    _db.Notes.Update(notesVM.Notes);
                }

                _db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            notesVM.PatientSelectList = _db.Patients.Select(i => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = i.FirstName + i.LastName,
                Value = i.Id.ToString()
            });

            return View(notesVM);
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work"? Do you receive any error? Please show us your action method and view, so we can see for ourselfs

Comment: No I didn't recive any error but I dont see that property Date is showing.

Comment: you can initialize an auto property this way: `public DateTime Date { get; set;  } = DateTime.Now`

Comment: That Date is a variable  local to your Upsert method, not a property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a constructor for your controller you can set the date property like this:

```
 public NotesController(ApplicationDbContext db)
 {
      _db = db;
      Date = DateTime.Now;
 }
```

updated my answer now that i have seen your constructor.

Comment: Yes, I have constructor in Controller. Please check **UPDATE** section where I added COntroller

Comment: I dont see in my constructor Date field from my Model 
https://imgur.com/v1aLL7z

Comment: You can set in setter like this:

public DateTime? MyDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

Comment: @Peres Thanks. It works now. I found where the error comes from